# AWS single ApiGateway with multiple services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am creating a design for my eCommerce application. It will have multiple services backed by AWS Lambdas. Orderservice, InventoryService, PaymentService, LoggingService, dashboardService are some of those services. I cannot give the exact number of services but it will surely be more than 15. As per this link [microservices](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) , a good microservices architecture should have one gateway that will route to the corresponding services. The code for my AWS ApiGateway with order Lambda function looks like below. 
 My question is that each of Orderservice, inventoryservice, paymentservice etc can have multiple routes for get, post, delete, put. Most of them will have nested resources. In this situation should I include api routes and lambda functions for all these services within the same SAM template. If yes, wouldn't it be a monolith Template. If I need to change in any service, I have to deploy the whole template and breaks the microservice principles. Ideally, I want to deploy all these services independently and yet share the ApiGateway. Is this possible ?. If not, should I create separate ApiGateway for each service in different SAM template so they can be deployed separately. This will cause authentication, authorisation, monitoring be repeated in all gateways which again doesn't sound like way to go. 
Please suggest what is the right way to do this.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"
Description: ApiGateway for the Ecommerce 

Resources:
  EcomApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: "2.0"
        info:
          title: Ecommerce Api
        schemes:
          - "https"
        x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: Validate body and params
        paths:
          /order:
            get:
              summary: Get the orders
              consumes:
                - "application/json"
              produces:
                - "application/json"
              responses:
                "200":
                  description: "200 response"
                  schema:
                    $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
                  headers:
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      type: "string"
              security:
                - Auth: []
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: "AWS_PROXY"
                httpMethod: "POST"
                uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${GetOrders.Arn}/invocations
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: "200"
                    responseParameters:
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
                contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"


  GetOrders:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: src/handlers/getOrders.handler
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - TestRole
          - Arn
      Events:
        List:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /orders
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref EcomApi
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned - create a separate API Gateway and share it with your APIs. [According to AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/best-practices-for-organizing-larger-serverless-applications/), it's recommended to have a separate API Gateway that serves multiple Lambda Functions.

I admit that I'm not an AWS SAM savvy, but doing it with the [serverless-framework](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/share-an-api-endpoint-between-services.html) is really easy.

Comment: The link you have shared shows single gateway with routing to multiple services based on resources like /products, /order and /buy. Interesting thing is it looks simple as is. But what if there are 15 + such resources. With each resource having 10+ methods of it's own. Is it ok to deploy all of those api in single cloudformation.

Comment: It really depends on your application. If your app is as big as you describe it, then you should break your CI/CD per service. Either way, deploying each service independently (as long as there are no dependencies) is a better approach. I think that your main obstacle would be setting the CI/CD to work with "path-based", and it's not supported by all CI/CD services. Here's an example of how to use a single API Gateway with multiple services - https://github.com/unfor19/serverless-template (serverless-framework)